# Slideshow images not showing in IE unless I inspect element (gone once I exit inspect element), but are fine in FF/Chrome/Safari/Opera

Tags: internet-explorer, slider, joomla2.5

I recently purchased a slider component for Joomla called JU Content Slider.

Here is the page I am working with - http://www.metzgers.com/test-13.html. This is a Joomla 2.5 site (upgrading is not an option for the time being).

In Internet Explorer (version 11 on my computer), the images in the slider are not showing up.

The odd thing is when I go to inspect the area with F12 Developer Tools, the images show up, but as soon as I leave developer tools, they disappear on the live site.

The images show up and work fine in all the other browsers (FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera).

How can i get these to show up in IE???

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

So this seems pretty late of a reply, open the developer tools and refresh the screen. Go to console and see if there is anything being sent from the website to the console. I know is past version of IE but not 100% sure about 11 that if the developer tools were not opened and a JavaScript tried to `console.log` something it would crash JavaScript on the page. However if the developer tools were open the page would work as expected.